# Is there any more efficent way to read files in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I am a newbie in C++ and I am trying to read integers from a large txt file.

But the speed is a little bit low and it takes about twenty seconds.
The file is about 20MB.
So I want to ask that is there any more efficient way to read integers?
Here is my full code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{

    std::ifstream fp("largeUF.txt");//The file need to read
    if (!fp)
        std::cerr << "fail to open!" << std::endl;
    
    
    int num;
    
    
    while (fp >> num)
    {
        //I just want to read all integers into the  variable
    }
}
```

I did this in visual studio 2019 and run the code.
The data can be accessed by the following link.
[The data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c56rg92ku72ecf/largeUF.txt?dl=0)

Comment: if reading 2mb of data takes 20 seconds, then you have a problem in code you didn't show. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Only as presented I would find it hard to imagine taking 20 seconds to read a 2MB text file of integer strings. What is between the `{` and the `}` of that `while` statement is probably pretty relevant.

Comment: On my system even an unoptimized build takes 300 ms to read a 6MB file.

Comment: You could try to first read the file at once as one binary data block, and parse it then in memory. That way you can easily measure which part takes how long.

Comment: Now I think that I have provided the minimal reproducible example.Please help me.Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/max0x7ba/parse-integers-benchmark

Comment: Even with that code and that text file it takes 1.5 seconds to run on my 8-year-old computer. Are you really sure that you have no code at all inside the while loop in your actual code?